# How to display div with inner text at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have div as per below example:
Now my need is to display Div at runtime without using jquery or javascript .So i would get that.

I need to use only asp.net (c#) :

```
<div runat="server" id="balancing" style="display:none;">
<div style="width: 330px; height: 30px; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="width: 330px; height: 30px; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="width: 330px; height: 30px; float: left;"  >
<div style="width: 150px; float: left;"><asp:Label ID="lblBalancing" runat="server" Text="Balancing:" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div style="width: 150px; float: left;"><asp:TextBox ID="txtBalancing" runat="server" CssClass="input" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe Push all of this into a `Literal` ! !

Comment: Actually am not getting any below example code you mentioned.

Comment: @nirav i think you should make visible=false on .aspx instead of using display & on at server side change this property of div to true.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can add dynamically an asp.net panel which generates div tag.

   ```
   // Create dynamic controls here.
   // Use "using System.Web.UI.WebControls;"
   Panel panel1 = new Panel();
   panel1.ID = "MyPanel";
   Form1.Controls.Add(panel1);
   ```
2. Create you div using [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) class

   ```
   HtmlGenericControl myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
   myDiv.ID = "myDiv";
   LinkButton myLnkBtn = new LinkButton();
   myLnkBtn.ID = "myLnkBtn";
   myLnkBtn.Click += new EventHandler(myLnkBtn_Click);
   myLnkBtn.Text = "I'm dynamic";
   myDiv.Controls.Add(myLnkBtn);
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myDiv);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for replying.. But i don't need panel at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can set style/CssClass for your div in code behide:

```
balancing.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display] = "Block";
//or
balancing.Attributes["class"] = "VisibleClass";
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.. i have tried this one but does not working at all

Comment: Try to remove style="display:none;" from markup and set it in codebehind when needed.

Comment: i have created new application and doing same thing that is working for it. but in current application that does not working that gives error like :base {System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl} = {InnerText = '((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)(((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)(balancing)))).InnerText' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'}

Comment: i am using balancing.Style.Remove("display"); in code behind that works for me in new web application but with current application that does not work

Comment: In which scope your control exists? Does it on page itself or within another naming container (In update panel, or in grid/repeater) ?

Comment: that is in same page or onSelectedIndexChanged of dropdown event

Comment: Can you put the whole ASPX markup? So it will be more clearly what happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6814/discussion-between-nirav-patel-and-alex-dn)

Answer (score 0):

Add an asp:Panel set as visible false, on post back make panel visible true.
Panel render as a div

Comment: try balancing.Attributes["style"]="display:block"; for show your div

Answer (score 0):

Display:

```
balancing.Style.Remove(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display);
balancing.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display,"Block");
```

Hide:

```
balancing.Style.Remove(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display);
balancing.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display,"None");
```

Comment: thanks for replying...i have tried this one but this does not work for me.